# Server-side includes on an iMac

Tags: macos, high-sierra, server.app, apache

I have failed for a year to find a way to run SSI (server side includes) on my iMac using the apache web server included with server.app.

I am wondering if the server app will allow server-side includes in a website hosted by Apache on High Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, Apple is removing the web server functionality from server app entirely in the very near future and documenting how you would migrate your data to apache to serve web pages.

- http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/apple-releases-service-migration-guide-macos-server/
- https://developer.apple.com/support/macos-server/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf

The PDF above has pages 22 to 32 dedicated to how you would migrate any data to an open-source web server. If you like apache, the [homebrew tool](http://brew.sh) might be a good one to use for managing that install and patching and service state (stop / start / restart the web server on command or boot).

From there, you'd be on your own (or need to ask a flown question - possibly on another site about how to enable the SSI you want on the version of the web server you have chosen).

Comment: Is homebrew the best here as apache would be better running as its own user not the installer

Comment: That’s a very good point @Mark I did qualify might be good for installing, patching and service control. Should I have said beginner use? I don’t know anyone that’s super technical that used server app so I kind of geared for the first couple times someone sets this up.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working today. I was not using the macOS Server app. However, my system had apache 2.4 on it already. I'm running macOS 10.13.5 (17G65) aka High Sierra.

I first had to follow the [instructions here](https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-macos-sierra-10-12-bca5a5dfffba) to get the server running. Note that I didn't bother with the PHP section because I don't need that functionality, and I didn't bother setting up multiple sites, either. So it basically involved putting an index.html file into my ~/Sites directory, which already existed.

Next I configured apache as described in section 3 of the above document. I created the /etc/apache2/users/myusername.conf and added the following:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
  AllowOverride All
  Options Includes Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note the extra `Includes` in the `Options` section. That is the first requirement to get server-side includes working. Note also that if you write `+Includes` as suggested in the apache docs, it will silently fail. This is what happened to me. Either all of the options have to have the `+` symbol or none of them can have it.

Next I edited /etc/apache2/httpd.conf in the following ways:

1. Uncommented the line for `module_include`:

   `LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so`
2. Uncommented the other modules suggested in the above docs:

   `LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so`

   `LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so`

   `LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so`

   `LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so`

   `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

   `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
3. Found and uncommented these lines:

   `AddType text/html .shtml`

   `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml`

That says that `.shtml` files will be processed for server-side-includes

I believe that's all I did. Note that you can look in Console.app under the section `/var/log`. If you twirl that open, there's another folder inside named `apache2`. If you click on that, there are several apache logs. As mentioned above, they are sparse and don't tell you every error that occurred, but do tell you some. I eventually discovered the problem by doing:

```
apachectl -M
```

and seeing that there were errors on the output of that command that led to the exact line in the config files that were bad. That was much more helpful!